# Explain on how to setup a JBOD Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid, sata

I have 3 hard drives. Two hard drives are SATA and one is IDE.
C:\ - 300 GB SATA Hard Drive
D:\ - 80 GB IDE hard drive.
And third disk is not installed, assume as if it was.

How do I merge all three disk to use them as a single one? Explain me how to setup a JBOD setup please. Or how I can achieve what I want. Running Ubuntu Server 14.04 on a PC. Just to make sure, I want to use all hard drives for the server as  a single volume.

I use this server just to play around, and use it as a web server. Just a testing environment, I'm building it from spare parts I find on my house.